# How to write data with xlsxwriter iteratively with no precise row:column coordinate?

Tags: python, csv, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to replace csv with xlsxwriter (I need a style feature for some rows in the document), so I'm trying to reimplement this logic in xlsxwriter:

```
    with open('text.csv', 'wb') as file_csv:
        fieldnames = ["Date", "Advertiser", "Offer", "Affiliate", "Affiliate Source", "Impressions", "Clicks", "Cost click", "Conversions", "Cost", "Revenue", "Profit", "Real profit"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file_csv, delimiter=",", fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for d in data:
            real_profit = str(float(d['Stat']['profit']) - (int(d['Stat']['clicks']) * 0.0004))
            writer.writerow({"Date": d['Stat']['date'], "Advertiser": d['Advertiser']['company'], "Offer": d['Offer']['name'], "Affiliate": d['Affiliate']['company'], "Affiliate Source": d['Stat']['source'], "Impressions": d['Stat']['impressions'], "Clicks": d['Stat']['clicks'], "Cost click": str(int(d['Stat']['clicks']) * 0.0004), "Conversions": d['Stat']['conversions'], "Cost": d['Stat']['payout'], "Revenue": d['Stat']['revenue'], "Profit": d['Stat']['profit'], "Real profit": real_profit})
        totals = response['data']['totals']['Stat']
        writer.writerow({"Date": "Totals", "Impressions": totals['impressions'], "Clicks": totals['clicks'], "Conversions": totals['conversions'], "Cost": totals['payout'], "Revenue": totals['revenue'], "Profit": totals['profit']})
```

How to implement it using xlsxwriter iteratively in for loop with writing total row in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DictWriter` is just a wraper to look up col number from the array `fieldnames`. You can write such wrapper yourself:

```
class DictWriter:
  def __init__(self, worksheet, fieldnames):
    self.worksheet =worksheet
    self.fieldnames = fieldnames
    self.nrow = 1

  def writerow(self, d):
    for k in d:
       ncol = self.fieldnames.index(k)
       self.worksheet.write(self.nrow, ncol, d[k])
    self.nrow += 1

  def writeheader(self):
    for ncol , fieldname in enumerate(self.fieldnames):
      self.worksheet.write(0, ncol, fieldname )
```

Usage:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
fieldnames = [...]
writer = DictWriter(worksheet, fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

# below comes your code 
for d in data:
  real_profit = str(float(d['Stat']['profit']) - (float(d['Stat']['clicks']) * 0.0004))
  writer.writerow({"Date": d['Stat']['date'], "Advertiser": d['Advertiser']['company'], "Offer": d['Offer']['name'], "Affiliate": d['Affiliate']['company'], "Affiliate Source": d['Stat']['source'], "Impressions": d['Stat']['impressions'], "Clicks": d['Stat']['clicks'], "Cost click": str(int(d['Stat']['clicks']) * 0.0004), "Conversions": d['Stat']['conversions'], "Cost": d['Stat']['payout'], "Revenue": d['Stat']['revenue'], "Profit": d['Stat']['profit'], "Real profit": real_profit})
```

Comment: Should I pass the fieldnames second time to the writerow method to write row in?

Comment: No, you shouldn't because the `fieldname` is already stored in the `writer` object.

Comment: But what does d variable mean? Is it initialized somehow during the object creation or not?

Comment: I mean, should we execute writerow by hands? And if yes, I see that d should be passed. And d is a fieldnames list by semantics.

Comment: `d` means the data (of type `dict`) that you need to write. Taken your example, it should be `{"Date": "Totals", "Impressions": totals['impressions'], ...}`. I will update the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: So, on the first iteration we just don't have .writeheader() method and use .writerow to write the header in the format {"Date": "Date", "Impressions": "Impressions" .... } etc?

Comment: I've added the `writeheader` method to the class. Pls understand this code I wrote is just a primitive class. You can add all the fancy functions on top of it. People on SO are not paid to do this for you.